# What is Entity Framework's logic for how it decides to insert multiple rows per INSERT statement?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm curious about what logic Entity Framework is using to generate its `INSERT` statements.  When I turn on logging, I'm seeing behavior similar to this...

I have a header table and a detail table

```
CREATE TABLE MyHeader 
(
    HeaderFieldOne VARCHAR(10),
    HeaderFieldTwo VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE MyDetail
(
    HeaderFieldOne VARCHAR(10),
    HeaderFieldTwo VARCHAR(10),
    DetailFieldOne VARCHAR(10),
    DetailFieldTwo VARCHAR(10)
)
```

In my code, I create a header with detail and save it to the database

```
void CreateRecord(MyContext context)
{
   MyHeader header = new()
   {
      HeaderFieldOne = "one",
      HeaderFieldTwo = "two",
      Detail = new List<MyDetail>()
      {
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
         new Detail("one", "two", "first", "second"),
      }
   }

   context.MyHeaders.Add(header);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now when I look at Entity Framework Core's logging, I see something similar to this

```
INSERT INTO [MyHeader] ([HeaderFieldOne], [HeaderFieldTwo])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
INSERT INTO [MyDetail] ([HeaderFieldOne], [HeaderFieldTwo], [DetailFieldOne], [DetailFieldTwo])
VALUES (@p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17);
INSERT INTO [MyDetail] ([HeaderFieldOne], [HeaderFieldTwo], [DetailFieldOne], [DetailFieldTwo])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15);
```

It appears that Entity Framework Core is inserting four rows into `MyDetail` in one query and four rows in another query. What logic is it using to decide how many rows to do per insert? In the actual program, it seems like Entity Framework Core never wants to go beyond `@p1999`. So does it start a new `INSERT` batch once it would go beyond `@p1999`?

Is that above logic configurable anywhere?

Comment: What specific verison of EF are you using? And have you attempted to look at either EF's source-code or IL disassembly to find out yourself?

Comment: I'm using 7.0.5.  I was hoping someone her knew the answer off the top of their head so I didn't have to go digging through the source.

Comment: It also depends on which RDBMS-specific library for EF you're using - as the exact SQL generated by EF/EFC is really controlled by that instead, rather than the Db-agnostic part.

Comment: I think you'll find the answer in `AppendInsertOperation` vs `AppendBulkInsertOperation` here : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Update/Internal/SqlServerUpdateSqlGenerator.cs

Comment: Thank you for that link.  Now I think I somewhat understand how it's appending multiple INSERTs into a single SQL statement, but I don't see what limits how many rows will be allowed in a single `INSERT`.  It seems like every function loops all the way through `modificationCommands` and appends each row to the `INSERT`.  Am I misunderstanding the code, or has the caller of `AppendBulkInsertOperation` already limited the number of elements in the `modificationCommands` parameter?

Comment: Is there any real problem related to this behaviour or why do you care?

Comment: I would assume there are performance reasons behind this default behavior, especially if you are on EF Core 7. If you are REALLY concerned with this, I would suggest trying to get in contact with `Roji`. As far as I know, he is the "performance guy" in EF Core team. if you asked here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues he will see and probably respond. But I agree with @Oliver, why does it really matter?

Comment: here is an open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29897 , apparently they are considering implementing an ExecuteInsert method similar to existing ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete methods to support proper bulk inserting. You could upvote this or reply to express why you need this functionality to be implemented.

Comment: Thank you @Mephisto for pointing me to those links.  I'm not having a problem related to this, I just thought it looked weird for EF to not do inserts one-by-one, but also not do them all as a single batch.  So firstly I wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something incorrectly to trigger this behavior, and then secondly I wanted to understand this behavior to better my knowledge of EF and database performance.

Comment: See [Maximum capacity specifications for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). Max number of parameters 2100. However, you still haven't specified which DBMS you are using.

Comment: See [Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#batching)

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderPetrov.  I am using SQL Server, so that explains it.